# Linking to python function in Github

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-flavored-markdown

I'm documenting the functions in a python library I'm working on in `.md` files and I want to link to a function in the codebase when I mention it. However, the best I've been able to do so far is

```
[logout()](https://github.com/my-username/my-repository/blob/83gxn83g84gnxi4wgfnxwuxnfguw4/path/to/filename.py#L122)
```

which links to the line number in the file where the function starts. However, if the function changes, then this link is no longer good. Ergo I would like to link to the python function directly in the current repo branch.

Comment: Isn't this already linking to a particular commit (and therefore robust..?)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Exactly my point. I want to link to the function in that branch of the repo, not a particular commit because the function will change.

Comment: We've had similar problems, best thing we came up with was doc generation software (Sphinx or mkdocs).

Comment: Aha, gotcha `:)`. Although I don't know the answer yet I'm afraid

Comment: If you want to write robust API documentation you are probably better off using a tool specifically meant for that such as [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).  I don't think GitHub has a way to do this (yet--it seems like something like it might be on the horizon though)